# How to get all pages of localbitcoin?

Tags: php, json

I've been researching the localbitcoin API, and I've seen that the json that is recovered contains a pager, is there any way to get all the results without these being paged?

```
{"pagination": {"prev": "https://localbitcoins.com/sell-bitcoins-online/vef/.json?page=1", "next": "https://localbitcoins.com/sell-bitcoins-online/vef/.json?page=3"},
```

Comment: hi mega, but what if more pages were added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a code somewhat like this to make sure you get all the pages:

```
<?php

function getAllPages($url, &$data)
{
    $file = file_get_contents($url);
    $jsonData = json_decode($file);
    $data[] = $jsonData->data;
    if(!empty($jsonData->pagination->next))
    {
        getAllPages($jsonData->pagination->next, $data);
    }

    return $data;
}

var_dump(getAllPages('https://localbitcoins.com/sell-bitcoins-online/vef/.json?page=1', $data));
```

This will keep looking for next pages until it reaches the last page. And will store all the pages in the `$data` array, which is passed by reference.

Comment: what is t time?he initial value of $data that you pass to function for the first

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt you don't send any value, it is a "pass by reference" variable, it will be created at that time

Comment: so this does not have any default value when called for the first time?
what the syntax will be like?

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt it doesn't require a declaration, that's all, but if you were to use it like var_dump($data); after you call the function, you will get the required values. It works the same way $matches works in preg_match()